# Retrofit: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: retrofit2

As I do for the get object "services" ?

```
{
"success": "true",
"code": "200",
"message": "The operation was successful",
"data": {
    "hairdressers": [
        {
            "name": "Jason Grant",
            "image_profile": "http:\/\/www.kbapi.co\/images\/header\/3.png",
            "open": "09:00:00",
            "close": "15:00:00",
            "id": "2",
            "id_saloon": "4",
            "services": [
                {
                    "name": "Corte",
                    "price": "8000",
                    "image": "http:\/\/www.kbapi.co\/images\/header\/1.png",
                    "time": "01:00:00",
                    "type": "W",
                    "saloon_id": "4",
                    "service_id": "3"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Corte",
                    "price": "8000",
                    "image": "http:\/\/www.kbapi.co\/images\/header\/1.png",
                    "time": "01:00:00",
                    "type": "C",
                    "saloon_id": "4",
                    "service_id": "4"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Corte",
                    "price": "9000",
                    "image": "http:\/\/www.kbapi.co\/images\/header\/1.png",
                    "time": "01:00:00",
                    "type": "O",
                    "saloon_id": "4",
                    "service_id": "5"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Herbert Davis",
            "image_profile": "http:\/\/www.kbapi.co\/images\/header\/4.png",
            "open": "10:00:00",
            "close": "16:00:00",
            "id": "3",
            "id_saloon": "4",
            "services": []
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you're telling Retrofit that you're expecting a `JSONArray` but instead you're getting a `JSON object`. I took a quick look at the result that you're using and it looks like it returns a `JSON object` and the returned object then contains the list you're interested in accessing. I can help you further if you post your `GET` call.

Comment: What happens is that I can not access the service [ ] , but if hairdressers . I could do in that case?

Comment: That depends on how the server is built. The server may send a status code that service is down, in which case, the response may deserialize correctly and you would have to check for the status code in onResponse(). The other possibility is that the response will be completely empty, the deserialization will fail and onFailure() will get called and you'll have to handle that call gracefully.

Comment: "services": [
                    {
                        "name": "Corte",
                        "price": "8000",
                        "image": "http:\/\/www.kbapi.co\/images\/header\/1.png",
                        "time": "01:00:00",
                        "type": "W",
                        "saloon_id": "4",
                        "service_id": "3"
                    }
                ]

Comment: What is the issue there?

Comment: {
    "success": "true",
    "code": "200",
    "message": "The operation was successful",
    "data": {
        "hairdressers": [
            {
                "name": "Jason Grant",
                "image_profile": "http:\/\/www.kbapi.co\/images\/header\/3.png",
                "open": "09:00:00",
                "close": "15:00:00",
                "id": "2",
                "id_saloon": "4",
                "services": []   
What happens is that I can not access the service [ ]

Comment: I see you what you mean. I haven't encountered this specific case but I predict that it would deserialize one part correctly and then return null for the rest. Do you have a model for all this?

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your list of objects with one more java class

```
public class Response {
    private boolean success;
    private int code;
    private String message;
    private List<Data> data;
}

public class Data {
    private List<Hairdresser> hairdressers = new ArrayList<Hairdresser>();
}
```

to generate this objects automatically you can use service [like this one](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Comment: What happens is that I can not access the service [ ] , but if hairdressers . I could do in that case?